# chef bash scope issues with commands.

Tags: ruby, bash, ruby-on-rails-3, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a chef recipe that goes to github and clones a repo. Unfortunately, I dont have git configured to use the certs and hence it has issues using https protocol with github.com.

My temp solution is to run the following and dont check for ssl.

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

This works when I do it manually so I put it in a bash block :

```
bash 'SSLVerify=False' do
  user 'root'
  cwd '/home'
  code <<-EOH
    git config --global http.sslVerify false
    echo "SSL Check Disabled for git"
    EOH
end
```

This succeeds and gives me the echo, but as the chef recipe comes to github clone part it fails again. Is the scope or bash only for the code in it or globally ?

Answer (score 0):

The 'git config' command updates the .gitconfig file which would be in the home directory of the user executing the git config command. I would suggest you to have a look into the config file if it is updated or not. It should have following entry

```
[http]
        sslVerify = false
```

If you see this entry then you would need to verify that the git clone is using the same config.

Comment: nah, as I said on the first chef run, the .gitconfig is not created, but when I run chef-client again, it creates the .gitconfig and the e recipe works fine, cloning whatever needs to be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

Add `environment 'HOME' => '/root'` to the resource. A lot of programs don't actually check the homedir of the user and assume `$HOME` is set.